# Yii2 Activeform afterValidate issue

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

In Yii 1.X version we can use `afterValidate` inside `clientOptions` property of `CActiveForm` class, please let me know the correct way to implement the same in Yii2

Comment: p.s. you have earned `Informed` badge and you still organizing question incorrect.

Comment: See the guide https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-form-javascript#activeform-events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw these changes. I am very very surprised why core team developers has decided to do so, now the events:

`beforeValidate`, `afterValidate`,
`beforeValidateAttribute`,
`afterValidateAttribute`,
`beforeSubmit`,
`ajaxBeforeSend`,
`ajaxComplete` function were moved to front-end side. They are triggered by `jQuery` `trigger` function. You can catch the event you need like this:

```
$("#FORM-ID").on("afterValidate", function (event, messages) {
  // Now you can work with messages by accessing messages variable
  var attributes = $(this).data().attributes; // to get the list of attributes that has been passed in attributes property
  var settings = $(this).data().settings; // to get the settings
});
```

Comment: They *weren't* moved. Yii2 has most of them for *both* front-end and back-end validation.